# How can i foreach all buttons in winforms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, button, case

Please can you help me? I have all buttons in winforms.designer.cs and I assign all buttons the same handler. The handler is `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`. I need to find all buttons and assign each a different `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`.

I tried this on a button, but it doesn't work.

```
private void createButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createButton.Cursor = NativeMethods.LoadCustomCursor(Path.Combine(collection.source, collection.cursor_hand));
    switch (Name)
    {
        case "createButton":
            this.createButton.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.create_on));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to be more clear. What do you want to assign? Are you getting errors?

Comment: I havent any errors. I want to search all buttony by name. I added one button to switch, but he does not call. And i dont know why.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can easily loop through your all buttons using [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method like this:

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.MouseEnter += createButton_MouseEnter;
    button.MouseLeave += createButton_MouseEnter;
}
```

And in your `createButton_MouseEnter` if you want to get current `Button's Name` you can do the following:

```
private void createButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var currentButton = sender as Button;
   var name = currentButton.Name;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You perhaps should consider making a recursive method as you might have a panel with a button on it.

so in your form's load you can go:

```
foreach(Control control in form.Controls)
{
       LoopControls(control);
}
```

the you can "play" with your button's like this as it's now a variable in your case
I will add some samples of other controls for some one who is looking to do similar

```
static void LoopControls(Control control)
{
    switch(control)
    {
        case Button button:
            if(button.Name.Equals("createButton",StringComparison.Ordinal)
            button.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.create_on));

            // other stuf if you need to...
            break;
        case ListView listView:
            // other stuf if you need to...
            break;
        case Label label:
            // other stuf if you need to...                  
            break;
        case Panel panel:
            // other stuf if you need to...
            break;
        case TabControl tabcontrol:
            // other stuf if you need to...
            break;
        case PropertyGrid propertyGrid:
            // other stuf if you need to...
            break;
    }
    foreach(Control child in control.Controls)
        LoopControls(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the buttons on your WinForm in this way:

```cs
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(Button))
    {
        //do stuff with control in form
    }
}
```

Use this code behind any event handler to loop through all of your controls inside your WinForm.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very simple, i'm sorry if i didn't understand the question:

```
if (sender == createButton)
{
    createButton.Cursor = NativeMethods.LoadCustomCursor(Path.Combine(collection.source, collection.cursor_hand));
    createButton.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.create_on));
}
 if (sender == otherButton)
 {
     //otherCode
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some common function for Multiple Forms then you can pass the Current Form object too

```
public class CommonHelper
{
   public void CreateButton_MouseEnter(Form currentForm)
   {
      var buttonsOnForm = currentForm.Controls.OfType<Button>();
      foreach (var btn in buttonsOnForm)
      {
         switch (btn.Name)
         {
             case "createButton":
             this.createButton.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.create_on));
             break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```