# How do I get the name/text of a radio button to be listed in an existing text file?

Tags: c#, winforms

(The text file was created in a separate form)

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach (RadioButton rb in this.Controls)
            if (rb.Checked)
            {
                StreamWriter details;
                details = File.AppendText("User Details.txt");
                details.WriteLine("Preferences:" + rb.Text);
                
                 }
```

When ran, it says: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton'.'

Comment: I believe you need to filter the Controls collection to the type you expect.  using System.Linq;   foreach (RadioButton in Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())

Comment: Don't roll your own prefs system; there's a perfectly good one built into winforms already

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of control you want by using `OfType<..>`.  This will return a filtered collection of controls cast to the specified type.

```
foreach (RadioButton rb in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
```

[Similar question found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362070/how-can-i-foreach-all-buttons-in-winforms-c)

You will need to import Linq in order to use this extension method.

```
using System.Linq;
```